# Dual of Zorn's Lemma?

Tags: lo.logic, ac.commutative-algebra, teaching

It seems to me that the dual of Zorn's Lemma should be true: if $S$ is a non-empty partially ordered set and every chain of $S$ has a lower bound in $S$, then $S$ has at least one minimal element.

Zorn's Lemma comes up quite often in Commutative Algebra, but I don't recall ever seeing a dual of it or any applications of a dual. Are there any interesting applications of the dual, assuming it is true?

P.S. I am not a logician.

Comment: The principle is equivalent to Zorn's lemma, if you just turn the order upside-down. 

Comment: This is too easy to be a homework problem.  I vote to close.

Comment: Hannay, in my opinion this sort of question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com and not here.

Comment: Maybe a more interesting version of the question is: If we take the axiom of choice to mean "Every epi has a right inverse," what can be said of the "axiom", "Every monic has a left inverse"? Of course I haven't thought about this at all, but my guess is that this would fail in a lot of topoi?

Comment: @Dylan Wilson: I agree that that is a more interesting "dual to axiom of choice".  But I disagree that it is a "version of the question" that OP asked.

Comment: But I do think @Dylan Wilson's question is interesting.  In GROUP, for example, if an epi has a right inverse, then it presents the domain as a _semi_direct product.  If a mono has a left inverse, then it presents the domain as a _direct_ product.

Answer (score 3):

If your poset is $\langle S,<\rangle$ and it has the property that every chain has a lower bound, define the order $R$ on $S$ which is: $aRb \iff b< a$.

It is easy to see that every chain has an upper bound, satisfying Zorn's lemma and that the maximal element in $R$ is the minimal element in the original order.